# question about proof of theorem of regularity

Tags: regularity-theory-of-pdes

i found a theorem saying that if u belongs to $H^{1}(\Omega)$ where $\Omega$ is bounded regular  domain of $R^{n}$ then $\nabla u^{+}=\chi_{u>0}\nabla u $ here $u^{+} =sup(0,u)$

the hint is to use this sequence: $\phi_{\epsilon}(u)=.\sqrt{\epsilon^{2}+ u^{2}}-\epsilon$ if $u\ge 0$ and equal  $0$ if $u\le 0$ then $\phi_{\epsilon}(u)$ converge to   $u^{+}$ in $L^{2}(\Omega)$

and  $\nabla \phi_{\epsilon}(u)$ converge to $\chi_{u>0}\nabla u$ in $L^{2}(\Omega)$
in fact we have :

$\lvert \phi_{\epsilon}(u)\rvert \le \vert u\rvert $ because $\sqrt{\epsilon^{2}+ u^{2}}\le \vert u+ \epsilon \rvert$  so $\eta_{\epsilon}(u)$ converge to $u^{+}$ in
$L^{2}(\Omega)$
And  $\lvert \nabla \phi_{\epsilon}(u)\rvert \le \lvert \nabla u\rvert $
and i conclude by saying that convegence in $L^{2}$ imply convergence in distribution
is my proof right?
thanks

Comment: you need to use dominated convergence to prove convergence of $\phi_\epsilon$ and $\nabla \phi_\epsilon$

Comment: thank you@daw so i just have to write that :$\lvert \phi_{\epsilon}(u)\rvert \le \vert u\rvert $ because $\sqrt{\epsilon^{2}+ u^{2}}\le \vert u+ \epsilon \rvert$  so $\phi{\epsilon}(u)$ converge to $u^{+}$ in
$L^{2}(\Omega)$
And  $ \lvert \nabla \phi_{\epsilon}(u)\rvert \le \lvert \nabla u\rvert $  because $\lvert \frac{u}{(u^{2}+\epsilon^{2})^{\frac{1}{2}}}\rvert \le 1$ right? and $ \nabla \phi_{\epsilon}(u)=\frac{u}{(u^{2}+\epsilon^{2})^{\frac{1}{2}}}\nabla u$